# How to do a group by in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 2 arrays, a type array and an amount array:

```
var type = ["AB", "AB", "K1"];
var amt = [5, 2, 3];
```

I am having a difficult time grouping them together.
I want the output to be an array like below:

```
final_array = [{"AB", 7}, {"K1", 3}];
/* 7 and 3 are the sum of each type */
```

Note: I am guaranteed that both arrays will be the same size, and also guaranteed the order which means `type[i]` belongs with `amt[i]`. So from the example above `type[0]` which is "AB" belongs with `amt[0]` which is 5.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Comment: What have tried so far?

Comment: There isn't a native or built-in function to do this - you'll need to write a function yourself. Have you tried this yet?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cb3xqudo/

Comment: Is this for Google Hash Code? :P

Comment: @adeneo - why not post that as an answer with an explanation of what it's doing?

Answer (score 2):

This is written verbosely, but you'd use an object, and then iterate over one array checking if the keys exist in the object, if they do, just add the value to the sum, if they don't, set the value as the sum etc.

```js
var type = [ "AB", "AB", "K1"];
var amt = [5, 2, 3];

var map = {};

type.forEach(function(x, i) {
    if (x in map) {
     map[x] += amt[i];
    } else {
     map[x] = amt[i];
    }
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(map, 0, 4) + '</pre>';
```

That leaves you with an object like `{AB: 7, K1: 3}`, which is probably what you want, but if you just have to have an array with objects that can't be looked up easily, you'd do

```
var arr = Object.keys(map).map(function(x) {
    var o = {};
    o[x]  = map[x];
    return o;
});
```

and you have `[{"AB": 7}, {"K1": 3}]`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var type = ["AB", "AB", "K1"];
var amt = [5, 2, 3];

var obj = {};
var final_array = [];
type.forEach(function(v, i) {
    var t = obj[v];
    if (t) {
        t[v] += amt[i];
    } else {
        t = {};
        t[v] = amt[i];
        obj[v] = t; 
    }
});


Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(e) {
    final_array.push(obj[e]);
});

document.write(JSON.stringify(final_array));
```